# Installing R in Suse Linux

Tags: opensuse

I am new to OpenSuse Linux.
My Suse version is:

*SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)

VERSION = 11

PATCHLEVEL = 3*

I want to install R in my suse linux.
I were trying to install through zypper by following set of commands:

```
$ cd /etc/zypp/repos.d

$ wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jeroenooms:/opencpu-1.4/SLE_11_SP3/x86_64/R-base-devel-3.1.2-3.1.x86_64.rpm

$ zypper refresh

Then install with zypper

$ zypper in R-base-devel
```

I followed this forum: https://forums.suse.com/archive/index.php/t-3735.html

But I am not able to install. Please help me with this.
And I am also not familiar to *YaST*. How can I install through *YaST*??

Answer (score 1):

> cd /etc/zypp/repos.d

You have to add the "jeroenooms.repo"

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jeroenooms:/opencpu-1.4/SLE_11_SP3/home:jeroenooms:opencpu-1.4.repo

---

EDIT: About the failing and disturbing repo, http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ : Please disable : Either mark `enable=0`, or move the repofile to a backup folder : `/etc/zypp/repos.d/back/` ...
... Or simply delete the (temporary?) unavailable repo.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. but after that when I am doing zypper refresh, it is throwing some error like:

Download (curl) error for 'http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/suse11/2.x/updates/2.1.3.0/repodata/repomd.xml':
Error code: Unrecognized error
Error message: Maximum (6) redirects followed

Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i/?] (a):

Please help.